# Como fazer o relaciomento de perguntas de um questionario

Tags: banco-de-dados, relacionamento, modelo-relacional, chave-estrangeira

Essa pergunta não e ligada diretamente a código, mas e a parte base do meu projeto, Atualmente estou dividido em 2 opções (que irei descrever detalhadamente mais a baixo).

Atualmente o UML está desta forma, (atende mais nas informações em azul e roxo; 
[image: UML]

Meu questionário será basicamente uma ferramenta a onde o usuário poderá montar o seu questionário com base nos que já existem pré cadastrados no sistema e assim responde-los (estou sendo bem breve sobre essa informação),

Agora vamos ao meu problema:

Cada questionário tem sua pergunta, que tem sua opção de resposta, que por fim tem a resposta correta,

O problema está em definir a opção correta, atualmente estou entre essas duas opções:

1. Entre deixar essa informação na própria pergunta (como por exemplo: opção A, ou idOpicao 123)
2. Ou deixar a informação na própria opção de resposta, (como por exemplo: boolean true para opção correta)

Porque a duvida entre eles;

O **(1)** em uma possível correção ou exclusão da opção de resposta, já bagunçaria com as resposta já realizadas dos respondidos, porque eles estariam relacionado ao `id`, e definir a opção A, B ou C em um questionário com  200 perguntas creio que isso teria um desempenho horrível, e tenho a impressão de ser uma grande gambiarra.

Já o **(2)** entra novamente no problema do desempenho, porque pra saber qual a opção correta seria necessário sempre percorrer as respostas para saber qual é a opção correta, um questionário com 200 perguntas e 5 opções de resposta já teria um peso razoável.

Em resumo meu problema é esse de como definir esse relacionamento de pergunta, opção resposta e resposta correta?

Na resposta eu gostaria de uma justificativa de usar o método respondido.

Comment: Sim, já fiz a correção

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Já o (2) entra novamente no problema do desempenho, porque pra saber
>   qual a opção correta seria necessário sempre percorrer as perguntas
>   para saber qual é a opção correta, um questionário com 200 perguntas e
>   5 opções de resposta já teria um peso razoável.

Difícil imaginar que isto possa ser pesado.

Se é a opção aparentemente mais correta e simples de implementar, eu começaria por ela antes de pensar em problemas de desempenho.

Se está muito preocupado com isto, cria uma tabela separada com relacionamento 1-1 entre pergunta e resposta. Esta tabela pode guardar apenas as referências para as respostas corretas. Também te ajudaria a deixar mais flexível seu sistema caso exista mais de uma resposta correta para a pergunta, o que não é possível na opção 1.

Comment: Estou pensando em manter dessa forma, e na tabela de reposta do usuário definir uma coluna `true/false` correta, assim eu nem precisaria percorrer a coluna de referencia,

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra opção seria fazer uma tabela associativa entre User_questions e Question options, indicando qual ou quais são as respostas corretas(ids) ou quais são os valores corretos.

Dessa forma seria possível até guardar um histórico de quais respostas já foram consideradas corretas.

Acho que desempenho é algo que você não deve se preocupar no momento, independente da forma que opte por resolver seu problema. Pois todas as soluções terão um desempenho muito próximo. O que você deve focar é na funcionalidade, na resolução do problema e na praticidade do desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas indique por meio de um atributo das alternativas se ela é ou não a resposta correta.
Não compreendi o que você quis dizer com :

> "pra saber qual a opção correta seria necessário sempre percorrer as perguntas para saber qual é a opção correta..."

Não sei se você está se referindo à parte da aplicação ou ao banco de dados, mas caso seja na aplicação basta você "pegar" a alternativa escolhida pelo usuário e verificar se ela é a correta ou não, sem precisar percorrer todas as perguntas/alternativas.

Comment: No caso você não especificou aonde eu definiria esse atributo, na resposta ou na pergunta.

Comment: especifiquei sim, quando eu disse : "indique por meio de um atributo das alternativas se ela é ou não a resposta correta"

Comment: Usando essa método, entraria no problema do update / exclusão / das pessoas que já responderam a pergunta em questão (caso ela seja a opção correta) qual alternativa você me daria para isso?

Comment: Não vejo uma outra alternativa, pois, simplesmente não consigo identificar um verdadeiro "problema" que esteja enfrentando. Não sei como funcionam as regras para seu sistema, mas a verdade é que não importando o método que escolha em algum momento updates serão realizados, tenha em mente que o update/exclusão só será realizado conforme a necessidade, então não fique se preocupando com desempenho, se for necessário terá de ser feito! Não há outro caminho.